# Temporarily forwarding client site requests via DNS to hosted maintenance page

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, cname-record

Is it possibly via DNS modification to forward a clients site requests to a maintenance page hosted on my own server?

I would like the option of easily rerouting a clients' web traffic through DNS so I can work on their site via IP... as a alternative to modifying their files, such as their .htaccess file.

**Example**

CNAME *, www -> ultimately resolving to "foo.com/clientmaintenance.html"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CNAME *, www -> ultimately resolving to
>   "foo.com/clientmaintenance.html"

No, that's not how DNS works. DNS CNAME (and ultimately A/AAAA) records resolve names to IP addresses, and that's where DNS stops. What you're proposing requires HTTP, which is a completely different protocol and application.

That said, you could create a simple vhost that performs this redirection for you.

Comment: Please explain...

Comment: You stand up a website to display the error message, and then make whatever modifications you need to the CNAME so that it points to this website.

Comment: By this do you mean... *,www -> boo.foo.com, with boo.foo.com serving the maintenance page?

Comment: That seems about right.